# linux shell scripting - to edit xml file and add text inside <argument> tag

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell

I have to come up with shell script to  automatically add and remove javaTCT agent JVM args from above xml file. Specifically, these two lines need to be added before any other javaagent:

```
javaagent:/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT/lib/ccqp-agent.jar -
Dccqp_properties=/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT/config/ccqp.properties
```

We are only required to modify the `<arguments>` section. Ideally, this new shell script will ask for user input as to the path of the `ccqp-agent.jar` and `ccqp.properties`. This is desired because the Enabler application has different environments that share the same servers. To provide an example of this…

1702 Enabler UPIE and MPIE are two servers

**UPIE**

```
javaagent:/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_UPIE/lib/ccqp-agent.jar - 
Dccqp_properties=/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_UPIE/config/ccqp.properties
```

**MPIE**

```
javaagent:/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_MPIE/lib/ccqp-agent.jar -
Dccqp_properties=/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_MPIE/config/ccqp.properties
```

`/lib/ccqp-agent.jar` and `/config/ccqp.properties` will always remain constant.

If we are able to prompt the user for the path of the files such as: `"Enter the path of the JavaTCT-Client directory"` so that they may enter in `/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_UPIE/` or `/opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_MPIE/` this would help tremendously.

Below is my **config.xml**

```
<arguments>

</arguments>
```

Here is the sample code I have written

```
echo "Enter the path of the JavaTCT-Client directory"
read  word
echo "The path you entered is: $word" 
find $word -type f -name "config.xml"
shell
```

Comment: .. and use `XML` aware tools to manipulate `XML` content like `xmllint`, `xmlstarlet`

Comment: Since you only have 2 possible paths, why not just simplify your find command to a one liner `find /opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_UPIE/ /opt/app/3psw/JavaTCT-CLIENT_MPIE/ -type f -name "config.xml`